# Unique identifier for Interop.ListObject from VSTO - C#

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-interop

I need a way to insert (or use an already implemented property that could serve as) a unique identifier into a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ListObject` instance.

The problem is that when I'm creating a new ListObject as:

```
var excelTable = worksheet.ListObjects.Add(ExcelInterop.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcExternal, DUMMY_CONNECTIONSTRING, false, true, cellRange);
```

I cannot rely on the `Name` property of `excelTable` to browse for it in the collection since the user could change the value of that property anytime afterwards.

After browsing trough the object properties I found nothing I could use out of the box (like a Tag property for example, which exists in a `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ListObject`type of object I cannot use at this point due to dependencies) ...and other weird stuff like a `DisplayName` that appears not only unable to be set directly but also to reflect the exact same value that the `Name` property has at all times (Why would you want to have 2 properties that reflect the same value at any time?).

I've thought on either creating my own implementation of this class or probably use the `Comment` property to store a GUID (which I don't know why kinda feels wrong):

```
excelTable.Comment = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Can you suggest of another way to accomplish this task?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite frustrating that there is no "Tag" (or similar) property that you could set on Excel objects. I'm facing the same issues as you. Here are two options that you can use:

- [alternative text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.alternativetext.aspx) property (for the table it is only visible by right clicking the table, selecting table and alternative text). This is probably a bit cleaner than Comment since the UI for comment is always visible.
- you could also generate a wrapper object that contains a direct reference to the ListObject. So one wrapper object for each created ListObject. This works fine until you save / open the workbook again. If you need to be able to identify the table again after reopening the workbook you would still need to write some id to Comment or Alternative text. You could probably do a clean implementation by using events like BeforeSave and AfterSave (add alternative text before save so it saves to disk, then remove it again after save so that the user doesn't see it. When the workbook opens you load up your wrapper objects and remove the alternative text).

Comment: Unfortunately AlternativeText is not allowed to be used in Excel2007, causing compatibilities issues.